# FFMPEG Pick First Audio Stream of Specific Language

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to extract a single audio stream of a specific language from a video file (which has around 10 different audio streams).

So I tried to use this command:

`ffmpeg -i file.mkv -map 0:a:m:language:eng output.mp3`

The problem is that the video contains multiple english language audio streams. So I get the error:

`Invalid audio stream. Exactly one MP3 audio stream is required.`

Here is the stream mapping:

```
Stream #0:1 -> #0:0
Stream #0:4 -> #0:1
```

From those two streams I only want the first one. I tried to with `-map 0:a:m:language:eng -map 0:0`, but this doesn't help in narrowing it down.

**Note:** I need the language filter as the stream numbers aren't consistent across multiple files. But the English language stream with the lower number is always the correct one I want to map.

Comment: This is a speculative suggestion, but can you do this with 2 piped FFmpeg calls? First to select audio streams of the selected language (with `-f mkv -acodec copy` output option) then the second call to pick the first stream of the piped streams and encode it as mp3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @kesh's post I found a solution.

By splitting the command into 2 and piping it in the next it is possible to get the expected behaviour.

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:a:m:language:eng -acodec copy -f matroska pipe: | ffmpeg -i pipe: -map 0:0 -c:a libmp3lame output.mp3
```

Comment: Nice. If you want to shorten your command, I think you can drop `-map 0:0` as FFmpeg only picks one audio stream by default

Comment: Using the syntax `-map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:m:language:eng -c copy -map_metadata:g -1` I get one video and two audio streams.